# Recursively go through array

Tags: php

```
$arr = array('aaa' => 
   array('bbb' => 
      array('ccc' => 
         array('ddd' => 
            'finally'))));

function walk($args) {
   $keys = get_func_args();
   // ...
}

walk('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
```

I want this function to walk through this multidimentional array and get the "finally" value. The walk() function retrieves random number of parameters, so the number of array dimensions is not known.

How do I do that?

I've though about some recursive way...but, well, I just cannot figure anything out. Could you provide me any suggestions?

Comment: free time project, Im just curious

Comment: Have you done any research? Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php ?

Comment: I'd have to use another function with array_walk_recursive(), right? I'd like to do this with just one.

Comment: What do you mean by `The walk() function retrieves random number of parameters` and what is your expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('aaa' => 
   array('bbb' => 
      array('ccc' => 
         array('ddd' => 
            'finally'))));

function walk() {

  $keys = func_get_args();

  $array = array_shift($keys);

  foreach ($keys as $key)
  {
    $array = $array[$key];
  }

  return $array;

}

echo walk($arr, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'); // finally
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for.........I have to change profession...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this small class

```
$walker = new Walker($arr);
echo $walker->find('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'); //finally
```

Class

```
class Walker {
    private $a; // array
    function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function find() {
        $temp = $this->a;
        foreach ( func_get_args() as $key ) {
            $temp = isset($temp[$key]) ? $temp[$key] : null;
        }
        return $temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new function that takes in an array of keys, and an index. With each new call, increase the index by 1, until it is the last key. thats when you know you have your answer!

```
 $arr = array('aaa' => 
   array('bbb' => 
      array('ccc' => 
         array('ddd' => 
            'finally'))));

function walk($myArray, $keys, $index) {
   if ($index == count($keys) -1){
      return $myArray[$index];
   }
   return walk($myArray[$keys[$index]],$keys,$index+1);
}

$keys = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
$result = walk ($arr,$keys,0);
```